Always Encrypted SQL Server with Sequelize
I'm testing to encrypt some data using always encrypted, but I'm having problems with comparison queries.
Sequelize:
mapDatabases.forEach(async (row) => {
        let model = row.model
        let host = row.Server.split('\\')
        const urimssql = `mssql://${row.UserID}:${row.Password}@${host[0]}/${row.Database}`
        db[model] = new Sequelize(urimssql, {
            define: {
                timestamps: false
            },
            dialectOptions: {
                options: {
                    instanceName: host[1],
                    requestTimeout: 60000,
                    encrypt: true,
                    columnEncryptionSetting: true,
                }
            },
            benchmark: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? false : true,
            logging: function (sql, time) {
                console.log({
                    time: `Query executada em: ${time}ms`,
                    query: sql
                })
            }
        })

Endpoint:
    app.get('/api/rh/funcionario/verificar-cpf', auth.verification, licenseValidation, async(req, res) => {
        
        try {
            const user = await Usuario.findOne({
                where: {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { '$UsuarioFuncionario.CPF$': req.query.cpf},
                      { '$UsuarioTerceiro.CPF$': req.query.cpf}
                    ],
                    Enabled: true
                  },
                  include: [
                    {
                        model: UsuarioFuncionario
                    },
                    {
                        model: UsuarioTerceiro
                    }
                ]
                })

            const cpfDisponivel = !user;

            res.json({disponivel: cpfDisponivel})
        } catch (err){
            res.status(500).json({msg: err.toString(), details: err})
        }
    });

Error:

"message": "The data types nvarchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_WORKFLOW', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Test_Database') and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.",

From what you're reading, queries with always encrypted require the use of Declare in comparisons. However, I don't know if Sequelize has native support for this.
Here is an example of an API call: http://localhost:92/api/rh/funcionario/verificar-cpf?cpf=879.987.987-87
